# Problems with LiPo Volt buck boost for a LED

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, lipo, buck-boost, bms

I need a little bit of help in understanding buck-boost converter.

I have 4 LiPo 18650 batteries in series an BMS to charge and discharge the batteries properly.
After that I added the buck-boost converter to get around 14Volts and boost it up to 30Volts to power my 30W LED, but my problem is that my LiPo batteries discharge very fast and than can't be charged again after a run. I don't know exactly where there's a problem.

[image]

Comment: Clarification needed: what "my LiPo batteries dies" exactly mean? Battery doesnt give off any more electricity? Battery refuses to charge afterwards? Battery physically breaks/leaks/smokes/explodes? Other than that, the diagram looks reasonable - as long as the BMS settings are adequate for the elements used.

Comment: Your power source is only as good as the weakest cell.  Your lack of full test results is telling us something.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem? A 30W led is going to drain 4 18650's before too long. Not all 18650's are made equal, check the mah of your batteries, too high or too low may be causing the batteries to heat up and waste energy during load balancing. Since youre using a bms, the batteries should only be able to discharge at a safe rate, maybe 40c. Is your battery life close to what you would expect from a battery life calculator?
https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/battery-life

Are you using the bms to charge them, or disconnecting the battteries? Your power input may not be enough to supply 35W and charge 18650 batteries.

Answer (score 0):

Your batteries in series combined will only be 2-3 Amp-hour of capacity, if the 30V , 30W LEDs consume  1 amp from the 30V circuit, due to conversion loss the Boost converter may be 80-90% efficient, meaning it's probably drawing ~35W from the batteries.  You will be lucky to get 1.5->2 hours runtime from this setup.

If the BMS has not been set correctly to protect the cells, or they are unbalanced how they drain, you may be over-discharging one or more of the batteries, causing them to not support recharging because they are too low to recover. Does the BMS have a under-voltage cut-off set up for 4 cell Lipo configurations?

Measure the cells after the system 'stops', and if any of the cells individually reads < 3V you may be in trouble and may have ruined the cells or may need some fancy chargers to try and bring them back to life.